# Regex to extract field values that MAY be followed by field names

Tags: c#, regex

Very simply: I'm trying to extract multiple field values from a string.

The string itself is the result of OCR process, so there are very few reliable assumptions about its structure.

Using "account type" and "account number" as examples (and assuming that this regex doesn't need to deal with variants of those field names), I want to extract the "account type" AND avoid pulling in potential "account number" field names or values.

**Notes:**

- Link to current attempt (including the examples): https://regex101.com/r/c59ud6/2
- I'm doing this in C#, hence my choice of syntax

**Example 1:** should extract "MyCheque Thing with Bells"

```
Account Type MyCheque Thing with Bells
Account Number 12345678 8741 5
```

**Example 2:** should extract "MyCheque Thing with Bells"

```
Account Type MyCheque Thing with Bells    Account Number 12345678 8741 5
```

**Example 3:** should extract "My Cheque Account"

```
Account Type: My Cheque Account    Account Number 12345678 8741 5
```

**Example 4:** should extract "My Cheque Accounting Account Number 3"

```
Account Type - My Cheque Accounting Account Number 3    Account Number 12345678 8741 5
```

I think the problem is with the way I'm trying to terminate words and lines, or maybe my use of lookarounds, but I haven't been able to crack it or find the same sort of question elsewhere. Non-regex solutions are easy enough, but partly due to the nature of the project and partly due to my own morbid curiosity, I'd like to solve this with just regex.

For reference, my initial regex in the regex101 link above:

```
(?minx)
(?<=^(.*account\s*type[\s\*:_-]+))
(\b[a-z0-9-_]+\b) (\s+\b[a-z-_]+\b) {0,9}
(?!\s+Account\s+Number)
```

Comment: Maybe just `(?si)(?<=account\s*type\W+)\b.*?(?=\s+Account\s+Number)`? See https://regex101.com/r/c59ud6/3

Comment: Try `(?mi)(?<=account\W*type\W+)\b(?:(?!\W+account\W+number(?!.*account\W+number)).)+`. https://regex101.com/r/agUqgs/1

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies both: 
Wiktor Stribiżew your solution doesn't solve the 4th example, but handles the first 3 quite simply.
Andrei Odegov you solution matches all 4 examples...but looks like something out of a book of spells to me :) works, but I'll need to spend some time working out why/how

Comment: @pcbulldozer So, you need to match the "longest" text, from the first occurrence of `account type` till the *right-most* occurrence of `Account number`, i.e. in my above regex, the `.*?` is the culprit. I updated the regex in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
(?i)(?<=account\s*type\W+)\b.*\S(?=\s+Account\s+Number)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/c59ud6/4).

*Details*:

- `(?i)` - same as `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`, makes the pattern case insensitive
- `(?<=account\s*type\W+)` - a positive lookbehind that requires `account` + zero or more whitespaces + `type` + one or more non-word chars text to appear immediately to the *left* of the current location
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `.*\S` - any zero or more chars other than a newline as many as possible ending with a non-whitespace char
- `(?=\s+Account\s+Number)` - a positive lookahead that requires one or more whitespaces + `Account` + one or more whitespaces + `Number` text to appear immediately to the *right* of the current location.